# soft question - Is Coq a good way of getting started with mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am a CS undergrad highly interested in learning math relevant to my field. The math courses at my university were informal and minimal. Unsatisfied, I started working through Terence Tao's *Analysis I*. While I enjoyed reading the book, doing exercises was a painful experience. Since I wanted to make sure that my solutions are formal, I had to check them myself many times and in the end I still wasn't sure if they were right. I only completed a few chapters.

Having a background in competitive programming I desired a tool to validate my proofs, similar to online judges. I learned about Coq and started working through *Software Foundations*. I've really enjoyed the exercises so far, but recently I realized that Coq's math is different from the one in Tao's book. For example Peano's axioms can be proved in Coq.

I am wondering if these differences keep being relevant throughout the whole analysis or they only matter while working close to the axioms?

And this raises my more general question: from the educational point of view, does it make sense to use Coq to learn math on my level?

Comment: I do not know Coq well, but I highly doubt that it is useful to understand math.

Comment: If I was in your position, I would try sending an email (or regular mail) to the chairman of a math Dept, at a University.  I would explain the situation, and tell him that I needed suggestions on which Math books to purchase for self-study on which topics.  Hopefully, the chairman would find a Math professor at his university that was willing to exchange emails with you.  In my opinion, for each subtopic of Math, finding the right book (**for you**), which is often different from what anyone else might recommend, makes all of the difference. ...see next comment.

Comment: The only general rules are [1] You want a book that has many, many exercises (theorems for you to prove, or computations for you to make) in it, since (in my opinion) $75\%$ of the learning takes place **during** the exercises.  [2] Don't skip any exercises.  [3] Use a forum, like MathSE, to focus on any problem where you are not sure.  See also [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for the details that MathSE reviewers are looking for, in an individual mathSE posting.